# Examples of integrals found using hyperbolic substitutions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I've read  that various types of integrals usually determined by involving $\tan$ and $\sec$ into the mix can sometimes be found more easily using hyperbolic functions.

As I'm not very familiar with the latter family, could someone give me some examples?

*Very* simple example: $$\int \frac 1 {1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Example, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.  Example:  $\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

Comment: I was thinking more about if someone could you me how this type of substitution makes the job easier, not just the functions haha.

Comment: The first, $x=\sinh t$. We end up integrating $1$. So we get $t+C$, that is, $\text{arcsinh t}+C$. We can get an explicit formula for the arcsinh by solving $x=(e^t-e^{-t})/2$, which with some manipulation is a quadratic in $e^t$. For the second, let $x=\cosh t$. We end up integrating $\sinh^2 t$, which can be done by parts or by using a double "angle" formula.

Answer (score 0):

> *Very* simple example: $$\int \frac 1 {1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Substituting in $x=\sinh\theta$ results in $\int\mathrm{sech}\,\theta\,\mathrm d\theta,$ which can be derived using trickery or using the substitution $u=e^\theta.$ But since this is a standard integral and subtituting in $x=\tan\theta$ much quicklier gives the answer $\arctan(x),$ this is is a non-example of hyperbolic substitution being easier than trigonometric substitution!

Otherwise, whenever the substitution $x=\tan\theta$ or $x=\sec\theta$ is called for, $x=\sinh\theta$ or $x=\pm\cosh\theta,$ respectively, are invariably preferable, due to nicer principal domains and being easier to differentiate and integrate. Here are some examples:

|  | integrand | substitution | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ | $x=2\sinh\theta\quad\color{green}✔$ | $4\int\sinh^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |
|  | $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ | $x=2\tan\theta\quad\color{red}✗$ | $4\int\tan^2\theta\sec\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |
| 2 | $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2}\quad(x\leq-2)$ | $x=-2\cosh\theta\quad\color{green}✔$ | $-\int\tanh^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |
|  | $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2}\quad(x\leq-2)$ | $x=2\sec\theta\quad\color{red}✗$ | $-\int\tan^2\theta\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |
| 3 | $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ | $x=3\sin\theta\quad\color{green}✔$ | $9\int\cos^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |
|  | $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ | $x=3\tanh\theta\quad\color{red}✗$ | $9\int\mathrm{sech^3}\,\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ |